# WebRequest System.NotSupportedException

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monodevelop, webrequest

Wrote this in monodevelop:

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;

namespace Hello
{
    public class Hello
    {
        public Hello () {}

        public static WebResponse world(string symbol) {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://yahoo.com");
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
        }
    }
}
```

Getting this exception where running:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.NotSupportedException: http://yahoo.com/
>     at System.Net.WebRequest.GetCreator (System.String prefix) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Net.WebRequest.Create (System.Uri requestUri) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Net.WebRequest.Create (System.String requestUriString) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at CNBC.Research.LookupUtil.downloadStockHistory (System.String symbol) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at CNBC.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0 
>   [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NotSupportedException: http://yahoo.com/
>     at System.Net.WebRequest.GetCreator (System.String prefix) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Net.WebRequest.Create (System.Uri requestUri) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at System.Net.WebRequest.Create (System.String requestUriString) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at CNBC.Research.Hello.world (System.String symbol) [0x00000] in :0 
>     at CNBC.MainClass.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0

I believe it's because it doesn't know what `http` is but I don't know how to add it.

EDIT:

This may shed light on the problem. It may be because I'm running the wrong version? I also am getting this error:

> WARNING: The runtime version supported by this application is unavailable.
>   Using default runtime: v4.0.30319

Should I be running version 3.5 for .NET 3.5?

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code snippet.

```
   public static WebResponse world(string symbol) {
        // Create a new 'Uri' object with the specified string.
        Uri myUri =new Uri("http://yahoo.com");
        // Create a new request to the above mentioned URL. 
        WebRequest request= WebRequest.Create(myUri);
        // Assign the response object of 'WebRequest' to a 'WebResponse' variable.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();

      }
```

OR

```
 public static WebResponse world(string symbol) {
        // Create a new 'Uri' object with the specified string.
        Uri myUri =new Uri("http://yahoo.com");
        // Create a new request to the above mentioned URL. 
        WebRequest request= CreateWebRequest(myUri);
        // Assign the response object of 'WebRequest' to a 'WebResponse' variable.
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();

      }


private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(Uri uri)
{
 var type = Type.GetType("System.Net.HttpRequestCreator, System, Version=4.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089");
    var creator = Activator.CreateInstance(type,nonPublic:true) as IWebRequestCreate;
    return creator.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
}
```

Comment: I wish I could say that worked but I still get the the same console output in the OP.

Comment: I too have this problem and the above solution was not successful in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

### Part 1: The Request

There is a known issue with .NET 2.1 and Mono 2.10 which caused this exact 'NotSupportedException'.  The code is located here:

https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/mono-2-10-9/mcs/class/System.Net/System.Net/WebRequest_2_1.cs

There are two sections which catch and return 'NotSupportedException':

- Line 130: Returns text 'Scheme {0} not supported'
- Line 153: Returns text 'Scheme {0} not supported' (from the URI)

### Part 2: The Response

The code is not returning the serializable object for a 'response':

```
public static WebResponse world(string symbol) {
      WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://yahoo.com");
      WebResponse response = request.GetResponse ();
      return response;
}
```

However, WebResponse implements IDisposable and thus should be inside a using() and the response should be what is being returned (using a String type so it can serialize back as either JSON or XML by way of the .NET Framework.

```
public static String world( String sSymbol ) 
{ 
      WebRequest rRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://yahoo.com");
      
      using( WebResponse rResponse = rRequest.GetResponse () )
      {
          return rResponse.ToString();
      }
      return "";
}
```

Next, exception handling needed to be added to not leave this unhandled.  Especially if you call this from a Web Service so as not to return an HTTP 500 Error when things fail for any number of reasons.  (Note: HTTP 500 Errors are painful because they don't return any details.  It's part of the HTTP protocol to drop the payload even if you populated it with detail data).

```
public static String world( String sSymbol ) 
{
      String sResponse = "";

      try
      {
          WebRequest rRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://yahoo.com");
      
          using( WebResponse rResponse = rRequest.GetResponse () )
          {
              sResponse = rResponse.ToString();
          }
      }
      catch( Exception ex )
      {
          sResponse = ex.ToString();
      }
      return sResponse;
}
```

Now, the last part.  The code for Mono 2.10 used .NET 2, but the proposed solution above was to force .NET 4.0's assemblies.  While you might get some code to work, it would be lucky if it does and you would be allocating two different .NET engines and CLRs and Garbage Collections.

Lastly, .NET 4.5 added support for TLS 1.2, so if you don't have to be vulnerable to hacking, upgrade to .NET 4.5 (better yet, .NET Core and you'll get TLS 1.3 support as well as cross-platform).  Make sure to recompile all of your source as .NET 4.5 (no mixing and matching of binaries).  Also, make sure to use 64-bit too since I don't believe any machines still use 32-bit CPUs anymore.

Answer (score -1):

I've faced this situation once I tried bundling my application with mono runtime to be used on machines that have no runtime installed out of the box.

the solution was to add ***App.config*** file to my project with the following contents (copied sections from machine.config file of my installed mono version)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.net" type="System.Net.Configuration.NetSectionG

    roup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
            <section name="authenticationModules" type="System.Net.Configuration.AuthenticationModulesSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <section name="connectionManagement" type="System.Net.Configuration.ConnectionManagementSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <section name="defaultProxy" type="System.Net.Configuration.DefaultProxySection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <sectionGroup name="mailSettings" type="System.Net.Configuration.MailSettingsSectionGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
                <section name="smtp" type="System.Net.Configuration.SmtpSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            </sectionGroup>
            <section name="requestCaching" type="System.Net.Configuration.RequestCachingSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <section name="settings" type="System.Net.Configuration.SettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <section name="webRequestModules" type="System.Net.Configuration.WebRequestModulesSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        </sectionGroup>
      </configSections>

      <system.net>
        <authenticationModules>
            <add type="System.Net.BasicClient, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <add type="System.Net.DigestClient, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <add type="System.Net.NtlmClient, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        </authenticationModules>
        <webRequestModules>
            <add prefix="http" type="System.Net.HttpRequestCreator, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <add prefix="https" type="System.Net.HttpRequestCreator, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <add prefix="file" type="System.Net.FileWebRequestCreator, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
            <add prefix="ftp" type="System.Net.FtpRequestCreator, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
        </webRequestModules>
        <settings>
          <ipv6 enabled="false"/>
          <servicePointManager checkCertificateName="false" checkCertificateRevocationList="false" />
        </settings>
      </system.net>


    </configuration>
```

Hope this will give you a clue!

Comment: What is being cited is not completely wrong, however it is not explained right.  If hosting this with IIS, then IIS at the OS-level uses a machine.config to control what are valid values allowed and what app.config settings are allowed to be overridden in the app.config file.

I believe the base issue is caused by a mix of .NET 4 and .NET 2.  The source code of the branch for Mono 2.10 shows the WebRequest is .NET 2.1 code, so forcing .NET 4 and .NET 2 is bad because they are two completely different architectures not intended to be intermixed.  See my answer below...